# URL not showing the right address after using servlet request forwarding

Tags: url, servlets, request

I am having a weird problem here, and I am really stuck, need to get this work badly.

so i have a page say index.jsp with a link say "a href=servlet?action=viewMenu". when I click on this link it will go to doGet() on my servlet and here is the code in my servlet.

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                 String action = request.getParameter("action");
                   if(action.equals("viewMenu")){
                        address = "/viewAdminMenu.jsp";
                   }
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
                dispatcher.forward(request,response);
     }
```

So the above code works fine but after request forwarding, my browser shows the url as

localhost/project/servlet?action=viewMenu. (with http:// in the beginning)

I don't want the above url as I could not set the basic authentication with tomcat, what I need is

localhost/project/viewAdminMenu.jsp (with http:// in the beginning)

I have tried to find information about this but haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the browser to go to a different URL, you'll need to tell it to redirect, rather than doing a forward in the server.  See the [`sendRedirect()` method of HttpServletResponse](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

*Forward*

- a forward is performed internally by the servlet
- the browser is completely unaware that it has taken place, so **its original URL remains intact**
- any browser reload of the resulting page will simple repeat the original request, with the original URL

*Redirect*

- a redirect is a two step process, where the web application instructs the browser to fetch a second URL, which differs from the original
- a browser reload of the second URL will not repeat the original request, but will rather fetch the second URL
- redirect is marginally slower than a forward, since it requires two browser requests, not one
- objects placed in the original request scope are not available to the second request

(*From [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181).)*

Comment: I see, thanks so much, I think I could sort out the problem from here. Thanks

Comment: Btw, I have one more question, sendRedirect does not seems to work with request.setAttribute. is there any work around for this?

Comment: @eds - you might consider asking that as a separate question (I think it's a good one, and I can't see an obvious duplicate).  Two options, which may well not be suitable in your case, might be 1) use HttpSession - then attributes can persist between calls.  2) send the attributes as part of the redirect URL, and modify your servlets to read them.